# "Иждивение" — происхождение слова

Tags: этимология

Присоединюсь к предыдущим спрашивающим по поводу этимологии)))
Меня заинтересовало слово "иждивенец". Человек, находящий на иждивении, — живущий за чужой счет.
А каково происхождение этого слова?

Answer (score 2):

Этимологический словарь русского языка Семенова:
иждивение.Древнерусское – иждивити (израсходовать, прожить).
Старославянское – иждите (прожить, истратить).
Первоначальное значение слова изменилось и в современном русском языке трактуется как «получать дотации, пособия». Слово фиксируется в памятниках письменности с начала XVIII в.

Фасмер- иждивение иждиве́ние "расходы, издержки (на жизнь, содержание)", церк., иждива́ть, иждиви́ть "израсходовать, прожить". Заимств. из цслав.; ст.-слав. из-жити дало иждити

Answer (score 1):

**Семенов А.В. в ЭТИМОЛОГИЧЕСКОМ СЛОВАРЕ РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА** происхождение  слова *ИЖДИВЕНЕЦ* объясняет так: 
Древнерусское – иждивити (израсходовать, прожить).
Старославянское – иждите (прожить, истратить).
Первоначальное значение слова изменилось и в современном русском языке трактуется как «получать дотации, пособия». Слово фиксируется в памятниках письменности с начала XVIII в.
Производные: иждивенец, иждивенческий.

**ПО СЛОВАРЮ БРОКГАУЗА И ЭФРОНА**:
*Иждивение*
1) обеспечение какого-либо лица (как правило, неработоспособного: больного, престарелого, несовершеннолетнего) средствами к существованию; содержание. Используется преимущественно в сочетании "на (чьём-либо) иждивении";
2) (устар.) деньги, средства, попечение. Например, "церковь построена иждивением купца".
[Ст.-сл. иждити - израсходовать, истратить. Глагол "иждити" - результат фонетического изменения "изжити" - "прожить".]
Иждивенец - человек, находящийся на чьём-либо иждивении; тот, кто постоянно пользуется помощью со стороны, не используя свои силы, собственные средства и т. п.